# Find the part of the solid $U$ that is inside the cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an exercise in the book that says:

Let $U$ be a solid that is defined by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1$. Find the part of the solid $U$ that is inside the cone $z = \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{3}}$.

As I understand, I need to use triple integrals and spherical coordinates to solve the problem, but I have a hard time trying to understand how to find the regions by which the part of the solid is bounded.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The solid U should be the part that's inside the upward facing cone, which is bounded by the sphere. The drawing should look like the upper half of this sphere.

[image]

(reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCone.html)

Calculate the range of $\phi$

$z=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{y^2}{3}}\Rightarrow z=\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}} \Rightarrow R cos\phi=\sqrt{3} R sin\phi \Rightarrow cos\phi=\sqrt{3}sin\phi \Rightarrow \phi=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Write this in spherical coordinates as:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\int_{0}^{1}Rcos\phi\;R^2sin\phi\;dRd\phi d\theta=\frac{\pi}{64}$

Comment: The answer is too small against 4/3π.

Answer (score 0):

That become cone of radius $\frac34$ and a part of sphere.

$\displaystyle\int_{\frac{\sqrt7}4}^1 \pi(1-z^2)dz$+$\displaystyle \frac13{\pi}({\frac34})^2*\frac{\sqrt7}4$

$\displaystyle=(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{\sqrt7}{6})\pi$